# Unwanted empty line at the beginning of document

Tags: theme-development, themes, rss

I have an unwanted empty line at the beginning of the document and I can't find the reason why it is happening. For default HTML I wouldn't have minded it but RSS doesn't work. I disabled all the plugins and no luck; the plugins don't cause anything. I started having this issue after I changed the file owner and permissions a long time ago but didn't care at the time. My permissions for all files and folders in the theme are "rwxr-xr-- myusername:www-data". I tried to add comments at the beginning of header.php, had no luck. The line exists even in /wp-admin. wp-login.php doesn't have it though. Where should I look for this line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to guess, the bit about permissions is peculiar.

The steps I would take to locate or at least narrow down the issue:

1. Verify or reinstall core files
2. Enable `WP_DEBUG` and see if there are related errors
3. Dump [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) and see if there are any unexpected/external files

Comment: I just updated my wordpress core, so I believe all the changes (if any) were reverted. I enabled WP_DEBUG and I am getting a warning "driver mismatch" because I am using MariaDB. I will work on fixing it but I have another Wordpress website on the same server and it works without the new line. So, I don't believe the issue here is the warning. I am checking `get_included_files()` now.

Comment: For a test, I just switched the theme file and the line disappeared. So, at least it decreased my list to a few files